# AppleScript: Can I send a keypress ignoring a pressed modifier?

Tags: macos, applescript, key, modifier

I've run into a rather specific problem where I would like to send a key press while having a modifier pressed **without** the modifier pressed. 
Basically, I press Option+F4 and want to send Command+F, not Command+Option+F.

Can it be done?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?